# Is it possible for Mexico to have a magnitude 9 earthquake?

Tags: geology, geophysics, plate-tectonics, earthquakes, seismology

Everyone has heard of the [Cascadia Subduction Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascadia_subduction_zone) and the potential threat it poses. However, I have heard nothing about The Cocos Subduction Zone, even though it caused a [devastating earthquake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Chiapas_earthquake) over 3 years ago. Does the Cocos Subduction zone pose the same threat to Mexico as the Cascadia Subduction zone to the US and Canada?